# Angular ng-click created in a string for datatables does not fire

Tags: angularjs

I'm using datatables with angular.  In my datatables, I'm using the render function to construct the element that needs to be added. This however doesn't seem to work with angular.  Is there something I'm missing?

For example:

```
var result =  "<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm right-buffer\" ng-click=\"view()\">View</button>";
return result;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about jQuery datatables plugin? https://datatables.net/

Comment: Alright - in that case, are you trying to write a directive that wraps datatables, or are you just initializing it directly in your angular controller/view logic somewhere? Or are you using an existing directive such as http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/?

Comment: I'm initializing datatables within the controller. Not using any directives.

Comment: Right - there's the problem. Just a few minutes and I'll post an answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has strict requirements around fitting in with the "angular way" of doing things. The specific problem here is that once data tables is initialized, angular doesn't parse and process the html elements contained within the data tables elements.

The angular way of doing something like this, is to put anything that does DOM manipulation into a directive - there's a lot of good [content available online on how to write directives to wrap jQuery plugins](https://www.google.com.au/#q=wrap+jquery+plugins+in+angular+directives), but with this particular plugin that's probably not a trivial thing to do yourself.

My advice - If you're set on using jQuery datatables, add this existing [jQuery Datatables directive](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) into your project and use that to initialize and manage your datatables instances in the proper way that angular needs it to be done.